# Is the Galois condition necessary in order to define an action on an elliptic curve?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, galois-extensions, galois-representations

At page 186 of the book "Joseph H. Silverman, John Tate - Rational points on elliptic curves-Springer-Verlag (1992)" there is a proposition where for any Galois extension $K/\mathbb{Q}$ it is defined the following action

$$Gal({K}/\mathbb{Q})\times E({K})\longrightarrow E({K})$$
$$(\sigma,(x,y))\longmapsto (\sigma(x),\sigma(y))$$
$$(\sigma,O)\longmapsto O$$
Later the author shows that it is an action and some good properties. But it doesn't seem  necessary the condition of that the extension is Galois.
My question is: is the Galois condition necessary?

Comment: At first glance, it seems to me that this condition is a reflection of the fact that the coefficients of your elliptic curve are in $\Bbb Q$. I think that if you take an elliptic curve over a larger base, and try out relation in the second line, it may fail.

Comment: The extension $\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{Q}$ is definitely Galois. Being finite is usually not part of the condition for being Galois (and it is impractical to make it part of it, since that is way too strict).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft thank you for that. But in order to define an action of $Gal(K/Q)$ on $E(\mathbb{C})$ is it necessary the Galois condiction of $K/Q$?

Comment: Something is garbled here: $\sigma(x)$ is not defined if $x$ isn't in $K$ (or at least in its splitting field). Are you sure it isn't an action on $E(K)$, not $E(\mathbf{C})$?

Comment: @DavidLoeffler. You are right, it is $E(K)$.

Comment: Right, and now the answer to the question should be obvious: if $K$ is not Galois, then (depending on your perspective) $Gal(K/\mathbf{Q})$ is either not defined at all, or is defined but doesn't send $K$ to $K$. So it won't give you an action on $E(K)$.

Comment: @DavidLoeffler, i studied Galois theory with the book "Galois Theory by David A.Cox". In that book for any finite extension $L/F$ it is defined $Gal(L/F)=\{\sigma:L\longrightarrow L\hspace{0.1cm}automorphism:\sigma_{|_F}=Id\}$.

Comment: @danihelovick if you take that as your definition of $\mathrm{Gal}(L/F)$ (others would denote this group by $\mathrm{Aut}_F(L)$, reserving the "$\mathrm{Gal}$" notation for Galois extensions), then this action is defined even when $K/\mathbb Q$ is not Galois. However, it won't have nice properties. For example, one key property is that the subset of $E(K)$ fixed by $\mathrm{Gal}(K/\mathbb Q)$ is $E(\mathbb Q)$. That won't be true if $K/\mathbb Q$ is not Galois (for example $\mathrm{Aut}_\mathbb Q(\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]2)$ is trivial, so will always fix $E(\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]2)$).